# Accessing object property through bracket notation regardless of the number of brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, accessor, notation

An object's properties can be accessed through bracket notation by doing the following:

```
let obj = {a: "test"}

obj["a"]
```

However, I was not aware that the same object's property could also be accessed by doing:

```
let v = ["a"] // An array

obj[v]
```

or

```
obj[["a"]]
```

or

```
obj[[[[[[[[[["a"]]]]]]]]]]
```

Just wondering, why is that?

I stumbled on this behaviour after storing an array into a variable and mistakingly using the variable/array, rather than the first item of the array, to access an object's property and surprisingly... it didn't throw an error but returned the value.

Comment: Because the result of `[[[["a"]]]].toString()` is just `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All object keys are strings. When you use bracket notation `foo[bar]` the variable you try to fetch will be converted to a string:

```js
const bar = {
  toString() {
    return "hello";
  }
}

const foo = {
  hello: "world"
}

console.log(foo[bar]);
```

When arrays are converted to a string, `join(",")` is implicitly called on them. And if an array has a single value, the result is the single value as a string:

```js
const arr = ["hello"];

console.log(arr.toString());
console.log(String(arr));
console.log(arr.join(","));
```

If you have nested arrays, each with one item, you'd still get a single string out of the conversion, since `join()` also converts all the members into strings, so with `String([["hi"]])` you (roughly) get:

`[["hi"]].join(",")` -> `String(["hi"])` -> `["hi"].join(",")` -> `String("hi")`

So, if you supply an array as a key, it works, as long as you only have a single value in each array:

```js
const foo = {
  hello: "world"
};

const arr = [[["hello"]]];

console.log(foo[arr]);
console.log(foo[String(arr)]);
console.log(foo[arr.toString()]);
console.log(foo[arr.join(",")]);
```

Comment: Beautifully explained.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(['a'].toString()); // "a"`

It's because a key needs to be a string and javascript does type coercion, converting the array to a string automatically.